# React Native WebView - Can't access to camera with Expo

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, expo

I am trying to create a WebView that accesses the camera while the session.
In Android - the WebView can't find the camera and throw an error.
In IOS - the WebView opens the camera, but only the front camera is in "Live Broadcast" mode.

My Code:

```js
useEffect(() => {
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await BarCodeScanner.requestPermissionsAsync();
          setHasPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
          setHasCameraPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
          setHasLocationPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await ImagePicker.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
          setHasCameraPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await Network.requestMediaLibraryPermissionsAsync();
          setHasInternetPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
        (async () => {
          const { status } = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
          setHasInternetPermission(status === 'granted');
        })();
 
      }, []);
```

app.json:

```js
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "React_Native_Secure.Me_WebView",
    "slug": "React_Native_Secure.Me_WebView",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
     
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "permissions": [ "CAMERA", "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE", "ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION", "INTERNET", "RECORD_AUDIO"],
        "versionCode": 3
      }
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the error? Have you added permissions to manifest xml file? Please check this as well - https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/508

Comment: Hi Aseem,
I am new in React Native field so maybe my next question is a littl0e bit awkward. I am developing with Expo, so I don't have a Manifest XML only app.json (Maybe I do and I don't even know lol)